# How to test with tox when pycurl is a requirement, under Windows OS?

Tags: python, tox

I have a project that I would like to test with tox. E.g. test the installation of the project with different python versions. I use tox for this. Under windows, I fail to do so, because of the following: tox creates a new venv for each target (e.g. python 3.6 3.5 3.4 etc.) and installs the requirements first. The next step would be to install the generated sdist and run all tests in the venv. However, requirements cannot be installed in the venv, because pycurl has no wheels uploaded to pypi for python 3.6. It can only be installed by downloading whl file manually and installing it by hand. But I'm using tox, and it will create a separate venv for each test run. I'm doomed!

How could I make this work? E.g. let's use tox to test a project that has pycurl listed in its dependencies list.

**UPDATE:** only 3.6 has no wheels yet, the others do. But the question is still valid (and the same question could be asked for any package that has no wheels for a specific python version).

Comment: *pycurl has no wheels uploaded to pypi* — what do you mean? There are many pycurl wheels at [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycurl) — except for Python 3.6.

Comment: All right, it is my fault then. The very first I tried way 3.6 amd64 and 3.6 x86, so the question is still valid. By the way, this could be a general question, because this problem is not specific to pyCurl. (Just in my case, I had trouble with pyCurl)